# Firebase keepSynced(true)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What are the trade-offs when I use sync on several paths in my Firebase database?

```
databaseRef.keepSynced(true);
```

I never clear the sync from these paths.

In addition, I might call databaseRef.keepSynced(true); several times on the same path. Is t a problem?

I'm also using

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

So what do I "pay" for this sync in terms of battery life, memory issues?

Comment: Note that, according to https://pamartinezandres.com/lessons-learnt-the-hard-way-using-firebase-realtime-database-c609b52b9afb, keepSynced also downloads that entire snapshot *every time a user starts your app*.

Comment: calling keepsynced(true) several times on the same path does not appear to be a problem. It's path specific and will reference the same location in local cache. I've tested adding it to the same path multiple times, then only calling the keepsynced(false) once on that path, and the sync was removed successfully.

Answer (score 31):

When you use the `keepSynced()` method, you're telling Firebase to download and cache all the data from `databaseRef`. I hope `databaseRef` isn't the root Reference of your Database because if it is, you're downloading your entire database and this is not a good practice.

You should use `keepSynced()` to cache nodes that are really necessary for your app to work offline.

You will probably be wondering how is it different from `setPersistanceEnabled(true)`. Well, `setPersistanceEnabled(true)` only caches data when there is a Listener attached to that node (when the data has been read at least once).

On the other hand, `keepSynced(true)` caches everything from that node, even if there is no listener attached.

Comment: Your answer was very valuable to help me find the cause of a slow query. We had code like this: `DatabaseReference reference=...;reference.keepSynced(true);reference.limitToLast(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent...`. This will download all nodes for that reference! The correct code is:  `Query query=...limitToLast(1);query.keepSynced(true);query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent...`.

Comment: Does setPersistanceEnabled(true) cache data for everything a listener has been attached to by that user's application, or in a multiplayer game database will it cache everything that every player has attached listeners to from their own devices/apps? Is this database listeners total. or total by the user that set the persistence(true)?

Comment: @Stotch yes, it will cache everything that you attach a listener to.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes will using either ‘setPersistanceEnabled(true)’ or ‘keepSynced(true)’ help when socket disconnects momentarily (wifi to cellular switch over) and an observer misses an event? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the newer devs like me, here's a breakdown of `keepsynced(true)` and `setPersistanceEnabled(true)`.

`keepsynced(true)` acts the same as having an observer() on the node. You want to place observers and `keepsynced(true)` at the lowest child node possible as it'll cost more in data downloads the higher up you place it.

`keepsynced(true)` caches that data to local memory (not disk) and keeps it up to date whenever connected to network so it's always available even if there is no active observer on that node. Example below:

```
ShoppingList {
    JunkFood {
        "Popsicles": 5
        "Cookies": 2
        "Chocolates": 4
    }
    GoodFood {
        "Lettuce": 1
        "Bread": 3
        "Oat Milk": 4
    }
}
```

If you place `keepsynced(true)` on a parent node like `ShoppingList`, and have no other observers set, if you're connected to the network, the list will sync and stay in sync with any changes in data in realtime. Then if you call `ref.child("ShoppingList/JunkFood/Popsicles").observeSingleEvent(of: .value)' it will return the value **5** from device memory cache (even if you are in airplane mode - offline). Data will be lost over app restarts.

Unless.....

You enable `setPersistanceEnabled(true)`.
`setPersistanceEnabled(true)` will cache all sync'd data to disk which will persist over app restarts. This incudes any downloaded data via `keepsynced(true)`, `.observe`, `.observeSingleEvent` and more.

There are notable downsides to `keepsynced(true)` in possible extra download costs. Although they should be less than a typical .observe function in that keepsynced uses hashing to try and get only the changes. https://medium.com/@puf/hey-pablo-firebaser-here-7bd12a6f6c8c

There are notable downsides to `setPersistanceEnabled(true)` in that data will be pulled from local cache when using `.observeSingleEvent`. So if your local cache data is older than the firebase data, you will not have the most fresh data. An example of this would be if you did **NOT** have keep `keepsynced(true)` on the main `ShoppingList` node, but **ARE** using `setPersistanceEnabled(true)` then call `ref.child("ShoppingList/JunkFood/Popsicles").observeSingleEvent(of: .value)` the data you get which is now equal to **5** will persist to disk cache. So if the value gets updated to **6** afterwards by another user, when you call `ref.child("ShoppingList/JunkFood/Popsicles").observeSingleEvent(of: .value)` again, you will return the **5** value from memory. So you would need to put keepsynced(true) or .observe() on the Popsicles node to keep it up to
date.

Upside of `setPersistanceEnabled(true)`, it keeps track of write attempts while offline and will try them again when connection resumes. Keepsynced(true) does not do this, as it applies to syncing and downloading only, not upload.

You may need a combination of both.
For my realtime 2 player game, i have no need to persist data to disk and it actually would make it difficult to ensure i retrieve only most up-to-date values, so i did **not** use `setPersistanceEnabled(true)`. But i **am** using `keepsynced(true)` on a few important child nodes to help with internet connection disruptions of players. There's a bit of art to this all :)