# Firebase isn't giving me real data when logged in on same account with two devices

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am using Firebase for my authentication and database, once I store user's exercise data on phone 1 and I refresh phone 2, the data is not there. Even when I log out of the app and come back in, there is no data. How would I go about this?

Edit: I fixed it, for those who might face a similar problem, there's a method you can call on your references called keepSynced which requires a boolean parameter and after that, your data will always be synced https://stackoverflow.com/a/42034913/10788522

Comment: Where do you save your data? Firestore?

Comment: @OleksiiZelenko realtime database

Comment: Need your code.